# Using For Loop to Generate Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, finance

I am working on some portfolio analysis and am trying to get a working function for pulling data for stocks, using a list of Ticker Symbols.  Here is my list:

```
Ticker_List={'Tickers':['SPY', 'AAPL', 'TSLA', 'AMZN', 'BRK.B', 'DAL', 'EURN', 'AMD', 
     'NVDA', 'SPG', 'DIS', 'SBUX', 'MMP', 'USFD', 'CHEF', 'SYY', 
     'GOOGL', 'MSFT']}
```

I'm passing the list through this function like so:

```
Port=kit.d(Ticker_List)

def d(Ticker_List):
x=[]
for i in Ticker_List['Tickers']:
    x.append(Closing_price_alltime(i))
return x

def Closing_price_alltime(Ticker):
    Closedf=td_client.get_price_history(Ticker, period_type='year', period=20, frequency_type='daily', frequency=1)
    return Closedf
```

Which pulls data from TDAmeritrade and gives me back:

```
[{'candles': [{'open': 147.46875,'high': 148.21875,
               'low': 146.875,'close': 147.125,
               'volume': 6998100,'datetime': 960181200000},
              {'open': 146.625,'high': 147.78125,
               'low': 145.90625,'close': 146.46875,
               'volume': 4858900,'datetime': 960267600000},
               ...],
  'symbol': 'MSFT',
  'empty': False}]`
```

(This is just a sample of course)

Finally, I'm cleaning up with:

```
Port=pd.DataFrame(Port)
Port=pd.DataFrame.drop(Port, columns='empty')`
```

Which gives the DataFrame:

```
    candles                                                        symbol
0   [{'open': 147.46875, 'high': 148.21875, 'low': 146.875, 'close': 147.125, 'volume': 6998100, 'datetime': 960181200000}, {'open': 146.625, 'high': ...}  SPY
1   [{'open': 3.33259, 'high': 3.401786, 'low': 3.203126, 'close': 3.261161, 'volume': 80917200, 'datetime': 960181200000}, {'open': 3.284599, 'high':...}  AAPL
```

How can I get the close price out of the nested dictionary in each row and set that as a the columns, with the ticker symbols (currently in their own column) as the headers for the closing price columns.  Also how to extract the datetime from each nested dictionary and set it as the index.

***EDIT***: More info

My original method of building this DataFrame was:

```
SPY_close=kit.Closing_price_alltime('SPY')
AAPL_close=kit.Closing_price_alltime('AAPL')
TSLA_close=kit.Closing_price_alltime('TSLA')
AMZN_close=kit.Closing_price_alltime('AMZN')
BRKB_close=kit.Closing_price_alltime('BRK.B')
DAL_close=kit.Closing_price_alltime('DAL')
EURN_close=kit.Closing_price_alltime('EURN')
AMD_close=kit.Closing_price_alltime('AMD')
NVDA_close=kit.Closing_price_alltime('NVDA')
SPG_close=kit.Closing_price_alltime('SPG')
DIS_close=kit.Closing_price_alltime('DIS')
SBUX_close=kit.Closing_price_alltime('SBUX')
MMP_close=kit.Closing_price_alltime('MMP')
USFD_close=kit.Closing_price_alltime('USFD')
CHEF_close=kit.Closing_price_alltime('CHEF')
SYY_close=kit.Closing_price_alltime('SYY')
GOOGL_close=kit.Closing_price_alltime('GOOGL')
MSFT_close=kit.Closing_price_alltime('MSFT')

def Closing_price_alltime(Ticker):
    """
    Gets Closing Price for Past 20 Years w/ Daily Intervals
    and Formats it to correct Date and single 'Closing Price'
    column.
    """
    Raw_close=td_client.get_price_history(Ticker, 
    period_type='year', period=20, frequency_type='daily', frequency=1)
    #Closedf = pd.DataFrame(Raw_close['candles']).set_index('datetime')
    #Closedf=pd.DataFrame.drop(Closedf, columns=['open', 'high', 
                                                'low', 'volume'])
    #Closedf.index = pd.to_datetime(Closedf.index, unit='ms')
    #Closedf.index.names=['Date']
    #Closedf.columns=[f'{Ticker} Close']
    #Closedf=Closedf.dropna()
    return Closedf

    SPY_pct=kit.pct_change(SPY_close)
    AAPL_pct=kit.pct_change(AAPL_close)
    TSLA_pct=kit.pct_change(TSLA_close)
    AMZN_pct=kit.pct_change(AMZN_close)
    BRKB_pct=kit.pct_change(BRKB_close)
    DAL_pct=kit.pct_change(DAL_close)
    EURN_pct=kit.pct_change(EURN_close)
    AMD_pct=kit.pct_change(AMD_close)
    NVDA_pct=kit.pct_change(NVDA_close)
    SPG_pct=kit.pct_change(SPG_close)
    DIS_pct=kit.pct_change(DIS_close)
    SBUX_pct=kit.pct_change(SBUX_close)
    MMP_pct=kit.pct_change(MMP_close)
    USFD_pct=kit.pct_change(USFD_close)
    CHEF_pct=kit.pct_change(CHEF_close)
    SYY_pct=kit.pct_change(SYY_close)
    GOOGL_pct=kit.pct_change(GOOGL_close)
    MSFT_pct=kit.pct_change(MSFT_close)
def pct_change(Ticker_ClosingValues):
    """
    Takes Closing Values and Finds Percent Change.
    Closing Value Column must be named 'Closing Price'.
    """
    return_pct=Ticker_ClosingValues.pct_change()
    return_pct=return_pct.dropna()
    return return_pct

   Portfolio_hist_rets=[SPY_pct, AAPL_pct, TSLA_pct, AMZN_pct, 
                         BRKB_pct, DAL_pct, EURN_pct, AMD_pct, 
                         NVDA_pct, SPG_pct, DIS_pct, SBUX_pct, 
                         MMP_pct, USFD_pct, CHEF_pct, SYY_pct, 
                         GOOGL_pct, MSFT_pct]
```

Which returned exactly what I wanted:

```
             SPY Close  AAPL Close  TSLA Close  AMZN Close  BRK.B Close
Date                    
2000-06-06 05:00:00 -0.004460   0.017111    NaN -0.072248   -0.002060
2000-06-07 05:00:00 0.006934    0.039704    NaN 0.024722    0.013416
2000-06-08 05:00:00 -0.003920   -0.018123   NaN 0.001206    -0.004073
```

This method is obviously much less efficient than just using a for loop to create a DataFrame from a list of tickers.

In short, I'm asking what changes can be made to my new code (above my edit) to achieve the same end result as my old code (below my edit) (a well formatted and labeled DataFrame).

Comment: Sounds like you have defined your specifications and have thought about using a loop to process the data returned by `Closing_price_alltime`. Seems like you could make a pandas Series for each ticker and use the datetime values for the index; then feed all those Series into a DataFrame. But you haven't let us see your approach and describe the difficulties you are having or asked a question.  Please read [mre] and [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the final function I wrote which accomplishes my goal:

```
def Port_consol(Ticker_List):
    """
    Consolidates Ticker Symbol Returns and Returns
    a Single Portolio
    """
    Port=[]
    Port_=[]
    for i in Ticker_List['Tickers']:
        Port.append(Closing_price_alltime(i))
    j=list(range(0, (n_assets)))
    for i in j:
        data = operator.itemgetter('datetime','close')
        symbol = Port[i]['symbol']
        candles = Port[i]['candles']
        dt, closing = zip(*map(data, candles))
        s = pd.Series(data=closing,index=dt,name=symbol)
        s=pd.DataFrame(s)
        s.index = pd.to_datetime(s.index, unit='ms')
        Port_.append(s)
    Portfolio=pd.concat(Port_, axis=1, sort=False)
    return Portfolio
```

I can now pass though a list of tickers to this function, the data will be pulled from TDAmeritrade's API (using python package td-ameritrade-python-api), and a DataFrame is formed with historical closing prices for the Stocks whose tickers I pass through.

Answer (score 0):

`Closing_price_alltime` return value:

```
d = [{'candles': [{'open': 147.46875,'high': 148.21875,
               'low': 146.875,'close': 147.125,
               'volume': 6998100,'datetime': 960181200000},
              {'open': 146.625,'high': 147.78125,
               'low': 145.90625,'close': 146.46875,
               'volume': 4858900,'datetime': 960267600000}
              ],
      'symbol': 'MSFT',
      'empty': False}]
```

You could extract symbol,datetime and closing like this.

```
import operator
import pandas as pd

data = operator.itemgetter('datetime','close')

symbol = d[0]['symbol']
candles = d[0]['candles']
dt, closing = zip(*map(data, candles))
# for loop equivalent to zip(*map...)
#dt = []
#closing = []
#for candle in candles:
#    dt.append(candle['datetime'])
#    closing.append(candle['close'])

s = pd.Series(data=closing,index=dt,name=symbol)
```

---

This will create a DataFrame of closing prices for each symbol in the list.

```
results = []
for ticker in Ticker_List['Tickers']:
    d = Closing_price_alltime(ticker)
    symbol = d[0]['symbol']
    candles = d[0]['candles']
    dt, closing = zip(*map(data, candles))
    results.append(pd.Series(data=closing,index=dt,name=symbol))

df = pd.concat(results, axis=1)
```

---

[pandas.DataFrame.pct_change](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html)

Comment: I edited my post to add info and conciseness, hopefully it helps, thanks for pointing that out. This code works great, Thanks. Only problem is it is only returning one stock's info, any way this can be edited to return all the stocks?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am getting `KeyError 0` on `symbol = d[0]['symbol]` with this new code however.

Comment: I can only work with the example data that you gave. It is a list with one item which is a dictionary. I assigned that list to `d` in my example so d[0] would be the dictionary. I don't see how you could get a KeyError with `d[0]` if `d` is a list. I assumed that `Closing_price_alltime` returns a list structured like your example.